# How to change password for Django Social auth loggedin Google+ user and facebook user?

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I am using social-auth in my app. I want to provide a functionality for google+ and facebook loggedin users to change their password using django change password form but for google+ and facebook  user current password is not available to change it so please anyone can help me with it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the user has current password or not. If not, then hide the current password input in your template. Short example:

```html
{% if user.has_usable_password %}

    <!-- Only show current password input if user has set a password -->
    <input type="text" name="current_password">

{% endif %}

...
```